# Anyway to iterate quickly over a collection of UDTs?

Tags: vb6

Let's say I have a collection of UDTs.  I populate it as below:

```
public type udtEmp 
    Id as long 
    Name as string
end type

dim col as new Collection
dim empRec as udtEmp, empDummy as udtEmp

for n = 1 to 100000
    empRec = empDummy  ' reset record

    emp.Id = n
    emp.Name = "Name " & n

    col.add emp, cstr(emp.Id)
next
```

Now I want to loop through it.  I am using a Long data type as the index to .Item()

```
dim n as long 
For n = 1 To 100000
    emp = col.Item(n)
Next
```

The code above works, but it's really slow - takes 10,000 milliseconds to iterate.  If I accessed the collection via a key, its much faster - 78 milliseconds.

```
For n = 1 To 100000
    emp = col.Item(cstr(n))
Next
```

The problem is that when I iterate over collection, I don't have the keys.  If I had a collection of objects instead of UDTs, I could do `for each obj in col`, but with UDTs, it won't let me iterate in that manner.

One of my thoughts was to have a secondary collection of indexes and keys to point to the main collection, but I am trying not to complicate the code unless I absolutely have to.

So what are my options?

Comment: `...secondary collection of indexes` thats what I used to do (array of ints usually).  thankfully those days are in the past for most of us...

Answer (score 1):

the elegance of the code or the performance of it is a serious decision you have to make. the choice should be based on the impact of the results. `for each` is elegant but slow and goes with objects and classes. but if the speed is a mater then use UDT and arrays.

in your case, i think an array of UDT is best suited for your situation. and to gain more speed , try to access arrays using `SAFE_ARRAY` (that you can google for it), the result is much impressive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a user typed class collection.  It'll provide the for-each iteration ability with great performance.

Easiest way to make that happen is through the Class Builder Utility (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa442930(v=vs.60).aspx).  You might need to first run the Add-in Manager and load the Class Builder Utility.  (I think that there were install options regarding these features when you installed vb6/vs6?  So if you don't see the Class Builder Utility in the Add-in manager it's could be due to that).

To match your udt sample, using the Class Builder Utility, first add a class (eg: Employee), with two properties (eg: EmpId and EmpName, long and string types respectively).  Then add a collection (eg: Employees) based on the Employee class.  Save it to the project (that will create two new class modules) and close the Utility.

Now you can create the new Employees collection, load it up, and iterate through it via index, key or for-each.  (note: don't use a pure number for the key - requesting an item by a key that is a pure number, even as a string, will be interpreted as an index request, it'll be slow and you probably won't get the desired item)

Also - once the new classes have been created, you can add customized properties and methods to them to handle whatever kinds of fancy stuff you may have requirements for.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim Emp As Employee
Dim colEmp As New Employees
Dim name As String

' Loading
For i = 1 To 100000
  colEmp.Add i, "name" & CStr(i), "key" & CStr(i)
Next i

' iterate with index
For i = 1 To 100000
  Set Emp = colEmp(i)
  name = Emp.EmpName
Next i

' iterate with key
For i = 1 To 100000
  Set Emp = colEmp("key" & i)
  name = Emp.EmpName
Next i

'iterate with for-each
For Each Emp In colEmp
  name = Emp.EmpName
Next Emp
```

**Timings**

On my system for the above code:
Loading time: 1 second
Index time: 20 seconds
Key time: 0.29 seconds
For-each time: 0.031 seconds

Comment: The problem is disposing of the collection.  It takes 2-3 seconds to set colEmp = Nothing...  More if you are dealing with a complex object.  A collection of UDTs or an array of UDTs takes no time at all.

Comment: Adding `Set colEmp = Nothing` to the end of the code above runs in about 0.6 seconds for me. If you have more elements added to the collection, or more complex items, then, yes, the time required to destroy the collection will be larger. Question - what is the ratio of iterating the collection/array/udt vs creation/destroying of same? If you frequently create new datasets that you only iterate through a little, then your udt approach could be better overall. On the other hand, if you frequently iterate through an infrequently created dataset, the user classes above could be better overall.

Comment: I've taken over an old project that does a massive amount of copying collections all over the place.  It was designed for a small number of items, but now its dealing with 100k items in collections, so it's super slow to be releasing objects.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer.  Even doing a straight port to .Net probably wouldn't help overall, though the set=nothing would/should return fast, you're just delaying the gc, then you'll take a hit some indeterminate time later.  Time to refactor and not be copying all those collections! (Glad to be Captain-Obvious-helpful there!)